# How to generate ten absolute Random digit in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to generate ten  absolute Random digit in SQL Server?

I tried `select ABS(CHECKSUM(rand()))`

but I can't control the numbers of digits!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RAND() returns a number between 0 and 1. So you don't require a call to ABS(). You can get a 10 digit random integer by multiplying the result of RAND by 10 to the power of 10 (10000000000) and then rounding the result (I have choosen floor in the example below but you could use CEILING() or ROUND()). Since 10 digits is at the limit of the int data type I'm casting POWER()'s as bigint.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 10))
```

References

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can force the random numbers to fall within a range such that they have the same number of digits, for example:

```
SELECT 10000 + CONVERT(INT, (99000-10000+1)*RAND())


SELECT len(CAST(10000 + CONVERT(INT, (99000-10000+1)*RAND()) as VARchar(20))) --5 digits
```

Because `rand()` is always `< 0 => (99000-10000+1)*RAND()` is always `[0,89,001)` therefore you'll end up with a random number between 10,000 and 89,000 which all have 5 digits.

[Other techniques for random numbers in general are here.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/)

Comment: good way but maximum numbers are only 9 digits 

SELECT 10000000 + CONVERT(INT, (990000000-100000+1)*RAND())

Comment: I think they can be as big as you define your data types ;)

Comment: oh, ya.

it was int ,hahahahha

yes now it's working very well .

tanks a lot

Comment: @Icarus:  Unless I'm missing something, that will not give you an EVEN distribution in your digits.  The left-most digit will only run from 1 to 8, omitting 0 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

This ***is*** 10 random numbers =)

[NOTE: I'm weird...I know]

```
SELECT 
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS One,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Two,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Three,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Four,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Five,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Six,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Seven,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Eight,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Nine,
  CAST((1/rand()*1000) AS INT) % 10 AS Ten
```

Results:

```
One Two  Three  Four    Five    Six  Seven  Eight   Nine    Ten
 6   0     1      2      1       0     1      5      2       5
```

Comment: =)  Couldn't resist (since you already got answers that were actually useful haha).